# How to debug android ndk texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, textures

I am writing android ndk code ( under frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger) , the function is to capture the framebuffer, blur it and then draw to framebuffer. Thus we have blur effect.

The code is using GLES / GLES2 and the pixel is handled against Texture.

My quest is: 
   How to debug the content of Texture (The pixels in Texture), for example, can I export it to bitmap or a image file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `glReadPixels` on the currently bound framebuffer to retrieve the data.

See this for more details:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml